# Generate Physicall DRL File

Tags: java, drools

I want to modify the DRL File at runtime/dynamically i.e write into the physical DRL file , I cant use decision tables or the Drool workbench, I will have a UI where fields will be selected and conditions set, based on this the needs to be written into the drl file and the modified file gets picked up and deployed into another system for deployment.

I am using DrlDumper but it is not writing into the physical file.

```
PackageDescr pkg = new PackageDescr();
RuleDescr newrule = new RuleDescr();
//Set new rule data here
pkg.addRule(newrule);
dDump.dump(pkg);
```

Comment: Which file? DrlDumper.dump returns a String.

Comment: Modify the .drl File with a new rule

Comment: There's no source info in a package so it doesn't work the way you think it does. Perhaps writing the result string to a file will do you good. Surely, this will lose all comments from the original source. - Using the non-stable API isn't recommended. You are on your own here.

Comment: Got it thanks.. Any other work around for this?